# Supporting bigger breasts?

Tags: biology, humanoid

I had an idea for a race of humanoids significantly larger than normal humans, but the females would need larger breasts than humans, for feeding bigger babies, obviously. How could their bodies adapt to support said larger breasts without issue?

Comment: I don't see the problem here: as an evolutionary trait, bigger women would display bigger breasts in proportion to their body, and they'd swell as pregnancy advances, to shrink back when lactation's over

Comment: The humanoids are larger than humans, and their breasts are also larger. Are their breast proportionally larger relative to their body size than a human woman's breasts? That is not clear from your post.

Comment: Huh? The breasts of human females are mostly fatty tissue. They have a mostly aesthetic function.There is very little relationship between the size of the breasts and the amount of milk produced. Consider our cousins the gorillas, who are *"humanoids significantly larger than normal humans"*: do their females have huge breasts?

Comment: I see this question as variation of a general "upscaling" problem - if we increase an organism in size while keeping proportions intact, can it properly function?

Comment: @Alexander Yes. Larger breasts don't equate to greater nutritional capacity. As AlexP said, human breasts are mostly fat tissue. A "significantly larger" humanoid species might indeed have larger breasts. Or it might not.

Comment: @elemtilas so it would be logical that large humans would have relatively smaller breasts to avoid health issues.

Comment: @Alexander Well, "logic" rarely comes into play as far as matters evolutionary go! If, early on, there was a particular advantage for small breasts over large (and there are indeed plenty!) then I'd suspect that evolutionary logic would result in a modern, small breasted Fifty Foot Tall Woman! If that advantage went the other way, well, modern large humanoid women will suffer for their ancestors' "logic".

Comment: pregfan, you need to promise me that you arent using us to write a hentai. Damnit. I came to this site to AVOID having to write sentences like that.

Comment: While you apprently assume the babies will be bigger, they don't necessarily need to be. They just need to do a lot more growing before adulthood. It's not unreasonable to assume their body and breast sizes will scale up proportionally. In which case, the supporting musculature will be bigger and stronger.

Answer (score 7):

Flat chested human mothers can nurse children into at least the 10 kilogram range.

Goat mammaries are in the same mass range as large human breasts and can produce a couple thousand calories of milk, that could support a 50 kilogram offspring. If you want to go bigger it probably makes sense to keep them mostly internal to reduce back and balance problems.

If external bulges are required for whatever reason cartilage or bone could form support for improbable structures and the spine could be more curved or the head set farther back to keep the center of weight over the hips.

The square-cube law limits how much you can scale up a body; the bigger it gets the more of it has to be support for the other parts, adding non-functional or cantilevered mass reduces what is available for doing useful work.

Answer (score 4):

Women with A-cub breasts have virtually no problem feeding children. This is because human breasts are used for sexual attraction, which is why humans are one of the few who have breasts developed and ready.

Cant find the article right now but apparently women in the "old" days would get more attention and with it presents (like food and care) from other men when they showed sexual readiness when their breasts swelled. An evolutionary trait developed with women who would show this trait all year around would get more attention, and making them unneccesary large made sure men were attracted faster. This made men uncertain when the women would be fertile and necessitated them to keep giving a woman attention for an extended period to ensure pregnancy.

So your larger sized women would be fine with bigger breasts, but also with current breasts or breasts like dogs or other animals that barely come out of the body.

Comment: Mammal glands are actually used to hide the sexual readiness. In all mammals but humans they send a message "I have just gave birth, not available to mate". By not knowing this, the human male is forced to stay with the female to catch the right moment for mating, and meanwhile taking care of the offspring.

Comment: @L.Dutch that's the point: In all Mammals but humans. Humans used breasts similar to how some Monkeys use their butt to signal sexual readiness. By faking this readiness the women would get more food and other support from males and have stronger, healthier lives which caused permanent breasts to become the norm.

Answer (score 1):

**The biggest Issue isn't Breasts (pun possibly intended)**

When scaling creatures upwards some organs can scale in size without losing function. Musculature, skeletal structures, and even mammaries are such body parts. There are no special adaptations needed to support larger mammaries on a larger human. The heart on the otherhand is a different story.

In cases of gigantism heart failure is one of the most common causes of death. The term "gentle giant" exists for a reason, people born with gigantism suffer life long heart illnesses. For thier impressive size they are often fairly weak with basic tasks required for living causing them to be left wheezing and nearly anemic. The human heart is built to support the metabolism of a regular human body. A larger heart beats slower, delivering less oxygen to the massive  body.

Large animals tend to be very deliberate and plodding with slower metabolisms than humans have, the few exceptions we can think of in modern day have hearts specially adapted to deliver blood to such a huge body, and biochemistry that makes more efficient use of oxygen. Dinosaurs dont count because the atmosphere had more oxygen back then.

In summary, no adaptations are needed for breasts, but such a huge human could not survive strenuous activity like childbirth without a different heart and circulatory system.